# Elasticsearch / xpath is not installed although DockerFile installed it

Tags: elasticsearch

I install elasticsearch on docker by the following Docker file:

```
FROM elasticsearch:5.6.4
RUN bin/elasticsearch-plugin install --batch x-pack
```

I see that it installed x-path successfully.

but when I run the following:

```
/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-plugin list
```

it gives empty result. also, I get on the following command:

```
curl -XPUT -u elastic 'http://localhost:9200/_xpack/license' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @license.json
```

the next result: `No handler found for uri [/_xpack/license] and method [PUT]`

what can be the reason and how I can install x-path on elasticsearch inside docker?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue. When it is starting up, the loaded plugins show and x-pack is there. Are you sure you're not getting confused between your local machine and your container?

Comment: @DarylVanSittert yes - elasticsearch is not installed on my local machine, just inside the container